# Ext Js, Ext.Ajax.request not working on mobile device

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I was trying to build an app with sencha touch 2, and phonegap, I'm using online phonegap build service, http://build.phonegap.com

I have a problem, the app is working perfectly fine on my computer, on all browsers, and it is also working fine on mobile phone when I open it from chrome browser, I also tried 'Phonegap App Desktop' which runs a server that transfers the app to your mobile device, the app works on the mobile there as well.

But not when I build the apk and install it on my mobile. Everything works except the Ajax request, here's a snippet for my ajax request.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://192.168.0.200/DVD/store.php',
    timeout:80000,
    callback: function(options, success, response) {
        var home = Ext.getCmp('home');
        home.setHtml(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

I was devastated cause' I could swear it worked before, so I created a new out of the box app and created a button, and added the above function to it, but that did not work.

What I'm doing is, building the app with sencha `sencha app build android`
Then I zip the android dir content, upload it to phonegap build service, and I then install it on my phone, everything works except the ajax request.

I don't have android SDK on my computer so I have to use phonegap online build

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Does any other request work? Smells like Cross-Origin issues, but without any error message, you won't get far. You should [try to get the error message from the request](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238414-Ajax-Request-Error-Handling).

Comment: Should not be a cross-origin error, I have received that error and I added the appropriate headers to the PHP file to allow all origins, on my computer I'm connected to 127.0.0.1 and I am requesting from 192.168.0.200, which is my own IP but still I did this to simulate whatever error that might occur cos of that, I fixed them, and it works just fine, except not after I build it it does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cordova 5.x you will want to check that your Content Security Policy is properly set in the head of your index.html.  You will want a connect-src clause in there allowing connections to http://192.168.0.200

So, use something like the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://192.168.0.200">
```

This should allow Android devices to access your server assuming that the Android device is on a network where 192.168.0.200 resolves to your server.

Should you in future port your application to iOS, you will also need to configure Apple's App Transport Security to allow wildcard access to all non SSL servers, or configure an exception to allow iOS 9 devices to make http connections to 192.168.0.200.  A blog post talking you through the process can be found [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).

Comment: I have tried this solution, after a few errors thrown, I added a few asterisks, still does not work on the mobile device, it is built using phonegap 4, I assume it uses cordova 4, so the above problem is not the issue, I noticed when I make the request from within the app I receive "network connection error" native notification, so is there an event log or something in android so I can read more about the error? I should note here that the server is accessible by the mobile device, I can access the file from chrome browser on the mobile device

Comment: A couple more things to check would be - do you have `<access origin="*" />` in your config.xml file, and in your platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I'm not building it locally so all those files your're talking about are being added to the package on the server, but I will try to build it locally and change the settings you recommended and see how that goes, but the strange thing is, there was a time when it worked. I will try your suggestion though, thank you very much

Comment: Just realized I didn't address "is there an event log or something in android so I can read more about the error" -- with the Android device connected to your machine by USB you can run this at the terminal to get logging: `adb logcat|grep Cordova` - running without the grep gets very noisy as you get all the OS log messages too but you might need those to diagnose the issue.  I use this on MacOS not sure if it's same for Windows.